# Python unittest mocking influxdb

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, influxdb

I want to test a class which passes data to an influx-database.
For that purpose I use influxdb.InfluxDBClient. For the unit-tests I want to mock influxdb.InfluxDBClient, but it seems that this is not working. I always get timeouts, so the mocking does not work at all.

This is the class I want to test:

```py
''' Client for influxDB1. '''
from influxdb import InfluxDBClient

class Influx1Writer:
''' Client to access influxDB1. '''
        
    def __init__(self, host, port, user, password, dbname, usessl) -> None:
    ''' Initializer, will be called from constructor. '''
        self.client = InfluxDBClient(
            host=host,
            port=port,
            username=user,
            password=password,
            database=dbname,
            ssl=usessl)
        self.client.create_database(dbname)
        self.client.switch_database(dbname)
        self.client.switch_user(user, password)
```

This is the test case

```py
''' Unittest writer for influxdb, version 1. '''
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock

from influxdb import InfluxDBClient
from influx.influx_writer_1 import Influx1Writer

class TestInflux1Writer(unittest.TestCase):
    ''' Unittests of Influx1Writer. '''

    host = "host"
    port = 8080
    user = "user"
    password = "password"
    dbname = "dbname"
    usessl = False

    def setUp(self) -> None:
        ''' Setup test fixture. '''
        mock_influx = MagicMock('influxdb.InfluxDBClient')
        self.handler = Influx1Writer(self.host, \
                                     self.port, \
                                     self.user, \
                                     self.password, \
                                     self.dbname, \
                                     self.usessl)
        mock_influx.assert_called_with(self.host, \
                                        self.port, \
                                        self.user, \
                                        self.password, \
                                        self.dbname, \
                                        self.usessl)

        super().setUp()

    def tearDown(self) -> None:
        ''' Tear down test fixture. '''
        self.handler = None
        super().tearDown()

    ###

    @patch('influxdb.InfluxDBClient')
    @patch('influxdb.InfluxDBClient.create_database')
    @patch('influxdb.InfluxDBClient.switch_database')
    @patch('influxdb.InfluxDBClient.switch_user')
    def test_01a_init_called(self, mock_client, mock_create_database, mock_switch_database, mock_switch_user) -> None:
        ''' Check InfluxDBClient is called with parameters. '''
        mock_client.__init__.assert_called_with(self.host, self.port, self.user, self.password, self.dbname, self.usessl)
        mock_create_database.assert_called_with(self.dbname)
        mock_switch_database.assert_called_with(self.dbname)
        mock_switch_user.assert_called_with(self.dbname)
        self.assertEqual(type(self.handler), Influx1Writer)
```

When the test is executed, a timeout will occur. This means that influxdb.InfluxDBClient is not mocked.

What am I doing wrong here?

---

Found the solution, thank you @blhsing

```py
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        ''' Setup test fixture. '''
        self.patch_client = patch('influx.influx_writer_1.InfluxDBClient')
        mock_influx = self.patch_client.start()
        self.client = Influx1Writer(self.host, \
                                    self.port, \
                                    self.user, \
                                    self.password, \
                                    self.dbname, \
                                    self.usessl)
        mock_influx.assert_called_with( host=self.host, \
                                        port=self.port, \
                                        username=self.user, \
                                        password=self.password, \
                                        database=self.dbname, \
                                        ssl=self.usessl)
        super().setUp()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the time you patch `influxdb.InfluxDBClient`, it is already imported into the namespace of the module `influx.influx_writer_1` so the module keeps a reference to the original `InfluxDBClient` even after `influxdb.InfluxDBClient` is patched. Instead, you should patch `influx.influx_writer_1.InfluxDBClient` so the name `InfluxDBClient` within the module `influxdb.InfluxDBClient` can actually be reassigned.

Also, you should use `patch` instead of `MagicMock` to patch an object. To patch an object for the tests in a `TestCase`, call the `start` method of the patcher in the `setUp` method, and then restore the original object by calling the `stop` method of the patcher in the `tearDown` method of the `TestCase`:

```
def setUp(self) -> None:
    ''' Setup test fixture. '''
    self.patcher = patch('influx.influx_writer_1.InfluxDBClient')
    self.patcher.start()
    self.handler = Influx1Writer(self.host, \
                                 self.port, \
                                 self.user, \
                                 self.password, \
                                 self.dbname, \
                                 self.usessl)
    Influx1Writer.assert_called_with(self.host, \
                                    self.port, \
                                    self.user, \
                                    self.password, \
                                    self.dbname, \
                                    self.usessl)

    super().setUp()

def tearDown(self) -> None:
    ''' Tear down test fixture. '''
    self.patcher.stop()
    self.handler = None
    super().tearDown()
```

Comment: Ok one step further. "self.patcher" doesn't have any asserts nor does "Influx1Writer." have. My version of python is 3.10.11, for which version this should work?